# How to display different textview when Spinner option is selected in Android

Tags: java, android

I am developing an application and I need to show a differents Textview when the user take a each option of a Spinner would be select in Android Studio, my code is the next:

```
Txt_Tiempo = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Txt_Tiempo);

Txt_Tiempo.setAdapter(adapter);

        Txt_Tiempo.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                if (i == 0) {

                }
                if (i == 1)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(Cesta_Activity.this, "En" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                if (i == 2)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(Cesta_Activity.this, "Completa la orden y muy pronto nos pondremos en contacto contigo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });
```

The Xml Code is:

```
When the first option of the Spinner is selected, a TextView should appear below the Spinner, but if option two is selected, a different TextView should appear, and so for all cases.
```

Comment: can you provide some examples?

Comment: I can not find examples but what I really want is to have several options through a spinner and that when the respective options of the spinner are selected, different texview appear, which may be hidden

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the textviews below your spinner and (Assuming you have set all the textviews' visibility to GONE) whenever (specific) option is selected you can set the respective textview visible by typing:

`textview1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`

Answer (score 0):

**Result:**
[image: Output gif file]
Use following steps:

1. Use all `TextView` at same position using `ConstraintLayout` or `RelativeLayout`.
2. Set all `TextView`'s `visibility = "gone"` in `.xml` file.
3. Then change `visibility` of every `TextView` when a new `spinner item` is selected.

Here is the `activity_main.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/category1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:text="Category - 1"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/spinner"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/spinner"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/spinner"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/category2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:text="Category - 2"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/spinner"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/spinner"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/spinner"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/category3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:text="Category - 3"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/spinner"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/spinner"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/spinner"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/category4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:text="Category - 4"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/spinner"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/spinner"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/spinner"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.32" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and here is the `MainActivity.java` file:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView category1, category2, category3, category4;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        category1 = findViewById(R.id.category1);
        category2 = findViewById(R.id.category2);
        category3 = findViewById(R.id.category3);
        category4 = findViewById(R.id.category4);

        Spinner spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        String[] spinnerArray = {"Category-1", "Category-2", "Category-3", "Category-4"};
        ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerArray);
        spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);

        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int category, long id) {
                showTextView(category);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
    }

    void showTextView(int category) {
        switch (category) {
            case 0:
                category1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                category2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                category3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                category4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                break;
            case 1:
                category1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                category2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                category3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                category4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                break;
            case 2:
                category1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                category2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                category3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                category4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                break;
            case 3:
                category1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                category2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                category3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                category4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Enjoy your work now.